# JMS Listener is getting down automatically

Tags: java, jms

I am using JMS in my application and noticed that the listeners are getting down automatically after sometimes(3-4 days). Did anyone face this issue before? Any suggestion from anyone will be helpful. Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: I faced a similar issue with an mqtt broker. There the problem was wrong keep alive interval setting in connection options. The listener has to send a heartbeat at regular intervals to the broker to keep the connection alive. Otherwise the broker will timeout the connection in case no messages are exchanged for long time. Check if you have any such requirement for the middleware you are using and if yes, set that in the connection properties.

Comment: Hi S.K, Sorry for late response. I was out of station. And thanks for your suggestion. But don’t have such scenario to check in a specific interval. It has been implemented from an existing application without any changes. But still I’m facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It’s late but the issue was that when there is disturbance in the connection with JMS server, the listeners were not able to re-established the connection. Because the listeners flag was set to be true, added code in the onException() method to set the flag false. And there is process which runs frequently to check whether the listeners are up and running. If no, it will re-establish the connection.

Thanks